# how to create a logic method that finds minimum number

Tags: java, math, methods, logic, jlabel

I have a problem creating the logic part of my button. I have tried many ways to sort it but am unable to think of the calculation.

I would like a method that once a button is pressed, takes a textfield value, does a calculation and outputs an answer.

Simple example...

There is an unlimited amount of boxes which can each hold 10 items. The user enters a random value into the textfield representing the number of items he has, lets say 21, and then presses a button.

In the background, a method will be performed that calculates how many boxes will be the minimum amount of boxes that the user will need. (How many units of 10). The answer will then be set to a label.

Hope you guys can help, thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class jjj implements ActionListener {

static JTextField tf;
JButton b;
static JLabel l2;

static int a;
static int quantity = 0;
static int units = 0;

static String g, s;
static JLabel q, hidden;

public jjj(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    tf = new JTextField();
    tf.setSize(180, 30);
    tf.setLocation(10, 30);

    b = new JButton("How Many Boxes?");
    b.setSize(180, 30);
    b.setLocation(10, 70);
    b.addActionListener(this);

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Answer:");
    l1.setSize(85, 30);
    l1.setLocation(10, 200);

    l2 = new JLabel();
    l2.setSize(85, 30);
    l2.setLocation(105, 200);

    hidden = new JLabel();
    hidden.setVisible(false);

    f.setSize(208, 300);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    f.add(tf);
    f.add(b);
    f.add(l1);
    f.add(l2);
    f.add(hidden);
}


public void Answer(){

hidden.setText(tf.getText());
a = String.valueOf(hidden);
quantity = a;
Calc();
}

public void Calc()

if (quantity <= 100){
            units = units + 1;
        g = String.valueOf(units);
        l2.setText(g);
}
    if (quantity > 100){
              quantity = quantity - 100;
        units = units + 1;
        Calc();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new jjj();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    l2.setText(null);
    Answer();
}
}
```

Comment: will u show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your current code is, but using something like this is probably what you're looking for:

```
public static int getNumberOfBoxes(double userInput, double numberOfTotalBoxes) {
    return (int)Math.ceil(userInput / numberOfTotalBoxes);
}
```

`Math.ceil` rounds up, so `21.0/10.0` would result in `3`.

---

IF your inputs are integers you could do something like this:

```
public static int getNumberOfBoxes(int userInput, int numberOfTotalBoxes) {
    int numberOfBoxes = userInput / numberOfTotalBoxes;
    if(userInput % numberOfTotalBoxes != 0)
        numberOfBoxes++;
    return numberOfBoxes;
}
```

In this second example, you simply to check if there is a remainder after the division.  If there is you'll need one more box.

Comment: Whilst thinking out a part of my project the other day, I realised that I couldn't use the division operator because I was using only whole numbers(not decimals). This problem ultimately is why I have come here, hopefully to see if anybody knew a.solution, maybe even had it before themselves. I hope from my code, you can see the approach I had attempted. This amongst other attempts have all failed.

Comment: Can you give an example input and example output?  I am pretty sure calling my second example in your `Calc()` method and assign the return value to your `units` you'll be good to go.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean? Unless you mean... I enter 99, press button, answer should be 1. However, if I type 199 and press the button. My method should realise that 2 boxes will be required, as only 100 items can fit in a box.Is this what you want to know?

Comment: Yeah, and that is exactly what my method does.

`getNumberOfBoxes(99, 100)` returns `1`, and `getNumberOfBoxes(199, 100)` returns `2`.

Comment: Sorry, Different variable names from what I used confused me. I sorted it anyway. Thanksfor the help.

Comment: No worries!  Glad I could help you out